# How can I calculate the block access required in Secondary multi level indexing

Tags: index, index-tuning, clustered-index, nonclustered-index

[Table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnPlW.jpg)

Given below are four relational schemas taken from the same University database.

> Student(***Std Id***, S_name, Address, Gender, Dept_Id, GPA)

> Department(***Dept Id***, D_name, Location)

> Enrol(***Std Id, Course Id***, Marks)

> Course(***Course Id***, C_name, Year, Lecturer)

Student relation has 30,000 student records and each record is 68 bytes long. These students belong to 15 different departments. Department relation has 15 records and each record is 30 bytes long. Each student must enrol to three (03) courses and all that information is available in the Enrol relation. Each record in the Enrol relation is 35 bytes long. Assume that the Block size is 1024 bytes.

If each index entry is 16 bytes long, calculate the total number of block accesses required to get a student record of a student belongs to a given department if a secondary multi-level index on the non-key attribute 'Dept_Id' on the Student relation is to be used. (Assume that the students are evenly distributed among Departments).
[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vmlu5.jpg)